# Adding Notes in a Timeline or Gannt

Tags: jira, project, project-management, trello, asana

I'm trying to plan and tracking one project with Jira/Asana/Clickup but I can't find one easy thing that I think It should be essential (just me apparently).

During a project things happens, for example an employee might be on vacation, a bug is come up and so on.

So, I'd like to add a note about these events and see them directly on the timeline.
I've found Runn.io but nevertheless it has what I want, it's very scarce about tasks and project managing.
[image]

I've tried any kind of Project Management SAAS but It seems none of them have what I need.
Surely there is something I'm wrong with how a process of project has to be tracked, but I think this feature is pretty useful.

Do you have any suggestion please? I'm freaking out.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

If you are following Agile then you need to make changes in resource availability. For instance in Microsoft azure devops, you can update capacity of each resource.

Hope this helps